# How to simplify MySQL to get all the sum of uniforms in different sizes based on month

Tags: php, mysql, select

**Table: TeamUniform**

| RegID | Name | Month | Tshirt Size | Tshirt Qty | Jacket Size | Jacket Qty | Pants Size | Pants Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Anna | June | M | 5 | M | 3 | M | 4 |
| 002 | Jane | May | XS | 5 | S | 3 | S | 3 |
| 003 | Emma | June | L | 4 | L | 4 | XL | 5 |
| 004 | Mary | June | S | 6 | S | 3 | S | 3 |
| 005 | Della | July | M | 6 | L | 2 | L | 2 |
| 006 | Myla | July | M | 4 | M | 2 | M | 3 |

I need to get the sum of each uniform (Tshirt, Jacket, Pants, Red Top, LongSleeve, Shorts, etc) in different sizes, so the result would look like this:

**Output: Total uniforms to be ordered for June (current month is April)**

| Uniform | XS | S | M | L | XL | XXL | XXXL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tshirt | 9 | 14 | 21 | 13 | 6 | 3 | 2 |
| Jakket | 7 | 9 | 12 | 9 | 9 | 2 | 1 |
| Pants | 8 | 17 | 14 | 12 | 15 | 2 | 1 |
| Red Top | 6 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 0 |
| Long Sleeve | 8 | 11 | 15 | 12 | 4 | 2 | 0 |
| Shorts | 7 | 14 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 1 |

## MySQL

```
    // Get the month 2 months from now
    $Month = date('F', strtotime('+2 months'));;

    // Query for Total number of Tshirts in size X-Small
    $sql_Tshirts_XS = "SELECT sum(tshirtQty) AS total_Tshirts_XS
        FROM TeamUniform
        WHERE month='$Month' AND tshirtSize='XS' ";
    $sum_Tshirt_XS = $conn->query($sql_Tshirts_XS);
    $sum_Tshirt_XS->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Query for Total number of Tshirts in size Small
    $sql_Tshirt_S = "SELECT sum(tshirtQty) AS total_Tshirt_S
        FROM TeamUniform
        WHERE month='$Month' AND tshirtSize='S' ";
    $sum_Tshirt_S = $conn->query($sql_Tshirt_S);
    $sum_Tshirt_S->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // Query for Total number of Tshirts in size Medium
    $sql_Tshirt_M = "SELECT sum(tshirtQty) AS total_Tshirt_M
        FROM TeamUniform
        WHERE month='$Month' AND tshirtSize='M' ";
    $sum_Tshirt_M = $conn->query($sql_Tshirt_M);
    $sum_Tshirt_M->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I also need...

```
// Query for Total number of Tshirts in size L
// Query for Total number of Tshirts in size XL
// Query for Total number of Tshirts in size XXL

// Query for Total number of Jakkets in size XS
// Query for Total number of Jakkets in size S
// Query for Total number of Jakkets in size M
// Query for Total number of Jakkets in size L
// Query for Total number of Jakkets in size XL
// Query for Total number of Jakkets in size XXL
```

It will be too many queries if I take it one by one.

**Then to display the sum of uniforms:**

```
    // Display the total number of Tshirts in size X-Small
    while ($tshirt_XS = $sum_Tshirt_XS->fetch()):
        echo $tshirt_XS['total_Tshirts_XS'];
    endwhile;

    // Display the total number of Tshirts in size Small
    while ($tshirt_S = $sum_Tshirt_S->fetch()):
        echo $tshirt_S['total_Tshirts_S'];
    endwhile;

    // Display the total number of Tshirts in size Medium
    while ($tshirt_M = $sum_Tshirt_M->fetch()):
        echo $tshirt_M['total_Tshirts_M'];
    endwhile;

    // Etc...
```

Is there a simplified way to query and echo all the results instead of the ones I have above?

Comment: Please provide your sample data as text rather than as images, that we can't consume.

Comment: `SELECT sum(tshirtQty) AS total_Tshirts_XS, tshirtSize
FROM TeamUniform
WHERE month='$Month'
group by tshirtSize` will give you quantities for all shirt sizes. I would restructure DB to store the month as a date column you then could run something like `where month(datecolumn) = month(now() + interval 2 month)` (that's a rough untested example, but gives idea of how using proper data types offers additional options)

Comment: If you want to limit sizes to a finite list can add to the `where` clause to limit that, `and tshirtSize in('s', 'l', 'm', 'etc')`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT tshirtsize, sum(tshirtQty) AS "total"
FROM TeamUniform
WHERE `month` = $month
GROUP tshirtsize
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Though you should also not concatenate variables into query text, use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Using the code you've given, plus I use `if, foreach` loop, has made the whole thing much, much shorter, and I got it to work! Regarding prepared statements, I will have to find examples and study first, as I am just starting to learn MySQL.